# How to write Unit Test for UserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, xctest, swift5, userdefaults

I have 2 functions where one basically retrieves string in User Defaults and another writes the string in User Defaults. I'm not able to understand that should I do the unit test or no? and I'm pretty new to the concept for Unit testing.

I scoured the internet for testing user defaults but I was advised to mock the test in the end.

My question is **If there is a way to test User Defaults what is the best way to do it?**

**Constants and Structs**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let defaultinformation = "ABCDEFG"

struct Keys {
    static let Information = "Information"
}
```

**Function where saves Information**

```
func SetDefaultInformation() {
    defaults.set(defaultinformation, forKey: Keys.Information)

}
```

**Function where retrieves Information**

```
func checkForInformation() -> String {
    let Information = defaults.value(forKey: Keys.Information) as? String ?? ""
    return Information
}
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> should I do the unit test or no

No. You know *what* UserDefaults does and you know *how* it works and *that* it works. It is ridiculous to test Apple's code. Testing `defaults.set` is just as silly; you know exactly what it does and you know that it will do it.

What you want to test is *your* code: not your retrieval from UserDefaults per se, but your *response* to that retrieval. Give yourself methods such that you can see what *you* do when `information` is a String and what *you* do when `information` is `nil`. As you've been told, a trivial mock can supply the back end, playing the part of UserDefaults and giving back different sorts of result. Just don't let your tests involve the *real* UserDefaults.

Comment: Hey @matt I have a requirement to do unit test on these functions basically add random strings and save and check if save. I know it's not needed and it makes no sense to test apple given function is there any other way to test other than mock test. I'm really new to testing. It would be great if you can shed some light on this.Thank You.

Comment: Sure, well, do you understand what a mock is? You can, for example, create a protocol to which both your class and UserDefaults conforms, and that requires `set(_:forKey:)` and `value(forKey:)`. Now it's easy for your test to interpose your class instead of UserDefaults. As I said in my answer, "a trivial mock can supply the back end".

Comment: No I don't understand mock. I was not able to wrap my head around it. Appreciate the help so far. Thanks

Comment: This is a good one to start: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/417

Answer (score 7):

```
class ViewModel {
     func saveUserName(name: String, userDefaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard) {
            userDefaults.set(name, forKey: "username")
     }
}
```

```
class MockUserDefault: UserDefaults {
    var persistedUserName: String? = nil
    var persistenceKey: String? = nil
        
    override func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String) {
        persistedUserName = value as? String
        persistenceKey = defaultName
    }
}
    
func testSavingUserName() {
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    let mockUserDefaults = MockUserDefault()
    viewModel.saveUserName(name: "Oliver", userDefaults: mockUserDefaults)
        
    XCTAssertEqual("Oliver", mockUserDefaults.persistedUserName)
    XCTAssertEqual("username", mockUserDefaults.persistenceKey)
}
```